# Formulario con textarea reseteable con texto predefinido

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un textarea con cierto texto predefinido editable dentro de la etiqueta y tiene contador de caracteres

Hola soy un ejemplo

Este textarea esta dentro de un formulario (form), me gustaria colocar un boton que por ejemplo si coloco mas caracteres dentro del textarea al momento de clickear el boton limpie solo el texto que agregue de más dejandome solo el texto predefinido.
¿No se si me explique? ¡Helpme!

Answer (score 0):

Deberías agregar tu código para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte.
Te dejo un ejemplo utilizando jQuery asumiendo una caja de texto y un botón que vuelva al texto original.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <input type="text" value="Hola soy un ejemplo" id="texto">
    <input type="button" value="Limpiar" id="limpiar">
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#limpiar").click(function() { 
         $("#texto").val("Hola soy un ejemplo");
     }); 
});
```

De igual manera te dejo el link en Jsfiddle para que puedas revisar el funcionamiento. [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/m6q7ta02/)

Comment: ¡Excelente Eric, me funciona perfectamente! 
Perdon por no agregar el código, la verdad no se como hacerlo, soy nuevo en Stack es mi primer pregunta que genero, muchas gracias por la ayuda